# Array within json object - How to populate it using python

Tags: python, json, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I have the following json:

```
post = { "file_name" : file_name, 
  "function" : [{ 
    "func_name" : func_name, 
    "start_line" : start_line, 
    "end_line" : end_line 
  }]
}
```

I am trying to populate the functions array for each file using python... but am not able ... Can someone help tell how to add more functions to that array assuming the we already have one entry with file name and the first function in that file ?

Comment: just to be clear I am trying to populate it as I go through a file and want to add function names to this object.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of how you can use and append to lists... This question shows no research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple as the function key can have list of dictionaries, so follow the following steps:

```
post = { "file_name" : file_name, "function" : [{ "func_name" : func_name, "start_line" : start_line, "end_line" : end_line }] }

#Define new function
new_function = { "func_name" : new_func_name, "start_line" : new_start_line, "end_line" : new_end_line }

#Append the new_function into post

post["function"].append(new_function)

print post
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thats perfect, so easy :-)